# Viewing Google Tag Manager tracking info

Tags: google-analytics, tags, google-tag-manager, tracking

I feel like this is a very dumb question, but here we go: I've set up two simple tags. Both are to track a page view – one to track if a certain page URL contains "utm_souce," and one to track if it doesn't. I previewed everything, and it's showing that the tags are working on their triggers...

My question is: where does this data go, and how do I view the results of the tracking – is it through the Google Analytics dashboard somewhere? I feel like I'm missing something, but I'm super new to GTM, so bear with me!

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, if they are GA tags that you setup, then you need to log in to Google Analytics to view the data

Comment: Found it. I had the track type set up as "page views," not "events." Once I set them to events, I found them under Behaviors in GA.